# Question on Cramer’s Rule

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Question]

I am looking and studying online for what it means for $det(A) = det (A^T)$

I thought it was some simple multiplication but then found out everything I had input is wrong.
These were my answers $[10,-10,5(-2)^T,(-1)^T10]$

I do not need the answer but if you provide it that is fine, I still have to learn how the process is.

Comment: Here the T means transpose of the matrix, not the Tth power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key properties at play in this question. Assume $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $c$ a scalar. Then

- $\det(M^T) = \det(M)$
- $\det(cM) = c^n \det(M)$

It is this latter property that makes your answer incorrect, because you need to account for the size of the matrix. (This fact is clear if you view the [proof](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/properties-of-determinants) of the latter property.)

Comment: oh I didnt account for the size of the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

We have $$\det(kB^T)=k^n\det(B^T)$$

Comment: Did not realize the size of the matrix affects it. Thanks!